# CSS - how to make the div display as shorter list box?

Tags: html, css

I have a custom drop down box for text fields, which is a very large in height when years are added from 2000 to 2020 (or for any large list).

How to make the list scrollable and visible 4 or 5 list items? instead of following full list:

[image]

```
  #combobox {
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;    
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:30%;    

    background-color:white;color:black;border:solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
  } 

  #combobox div {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;
  }

  #combobox div:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }  

  <div id="combobox" style=""  >
    <div>2000</div><div>2001</div><div>2002</div><div>2003</div><div>2004</div><div>2005</div><div>2006</div><div>2007</div><div>2008</div><div>2009</div><div>2010</div><div>2011</div><div>2012</div><div>2013</div><div>2014</div><div>2015</div><div>2016</div><div>2017</div><div>2018</div><div>2019</div><div>2020</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `overflow: scroll` to your div and give it a set height:

```
  #combobox {
   ...
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 100px;
  }
```

You can adjust the height to show the number of items that you need.

**TIP**

To make the scroll look nicer try something like [perfectScroll](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kirFofe.png - Its not showing any scrolling only showing 2 items.

Comment: try adjusting the height (height: 200px)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `max-height` you want, and `overflow-y: scroll;`

Using `max-height` is preferrable over `height` in case your list contains less items.

```css
#combobox {
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 245px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#combobox div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
#combobox div:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="combobox" style="">
  <div>2000</div>
  <div>2001</div>
  <div>2002</div>
  <div>2003</div>
  <div>2004</div>
  <div>2005</div>
  <div>2006</div>
  <div>2007</div>
  <div>2008</div>
  <div>2009</div>
  <div>2010</div>
  <div>2011</div>
  <div>2012</div>
  <div>2013</div>
  <div>2014</div>
  <div>2015</div>
  <div>2016</div>
  <div>2017</div>
  <div>2018</div>
  <div>2019</div>
  <div>2020</div>
</div>
```